# how to write custom item readers in spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am new to Spring batch, I need to customize ItemReaders in Spring batch. How can I do that? My requirement is I have feeds coming from multiple source system which are stored in different staging tables. Now based upon the source system I have to query the respective staging table. For this I need to write a custom ItemReader. Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: Can you share your current state of work?

Comment: you can write your own reader using delegation or directly implementing `ItemReader<T>` interface. Be more specific about your failed tries and we can help you in a better way

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.NonTransientResourceException;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ParseException;
import org.springframework.batch.item.UnexpectedInputException;


public class YoutItemReader implements ItemReader<YourObject> {

    @Override
    public YourObject read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {

        // You Code Here
        YourObject oa = new YourObject();
        return oa;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

check below documentation point 6.9

http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html

you have to create rowmapper and use JdbcCursorItemReader or JdbcPagingItemReader also there are other options using JPA and hibernate,and if you are reading from different tables you can make view concatenating all these tables